# How to print output while executable is running in windows batch for loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using a for loop to execute another executable and capturing the output. The output is a set of variables such as

```
Name=Jim
Address=1234 Main Ave
Phone=425-555-0202
```

However it takes quite a while for this executable to run. I am capturing the output and setting environment variables via:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('fetch.exe <options>') do (
    echo "%%a"
    set "%%a"
)
```

This is working fine, however if fetch.exe takes 120 seconds to run, the echo portion of that loop does not run until after the process is completed 120 seconds later. An easy test is to create a batch file such as

```
@echo 1
@echo 2
@echo 3
@echo 4
timeout /t 30
```

Then call that from the command line via `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('call test.cmd') do (@echo "%a")`

You will not see any output for 30 seconds.

How can I immediately start seeing the output of the command being executed?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible with a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) since it always waits until the command after `in` has finished...

Comment: Well, let's take the process `fetch.exe <options>` by itself. When you execute only that from cmdline, how long before you see any output to the screen? That is the same principal here. `For` is waiting on the process to to complete before it can use the output from the command.

Comment: The __command line__ specified between `'` is executed by `for` (more precise `cmd.exe` processing batch file with `for`) by executing `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified __command line__ appended. So started is one more command process in background to execute the specified command line. The command process executing `for` waits for the termination of started second `cmd.exe` before it processes the captured output written to handle __STDOUT__ of second command process. So it is impossible to get processed by first `cmd.exe` respectively `for` the output of second `cmd.exe` while it still runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, `FOR /F` can't handle this, as it waits for the completion of the invoked command.

But you can get it working with an async pattern.
The producer works in its own thread.

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:function:\..\MyBatchFile.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

break > async.tmp
start "" /b "cmd /c "%~d0\:producer:\..\%~pnx0"
call :consumer
exit /b

:producer
(
  call slowOutput.bat 
  (echo ende)
) > async.tmp
exit /b

:consumer
echo c
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
< async.tmp call :_consumer
exit /b

:_consumer
set "line="
set /p line=

if not defined line goto :_consumer
if "!line!" EQU "ende" exit /b

echo(!line!
goto :_consumer
```

Comment: I think I am going to have to play with this to get it to work for my use case, but either way that is a clever answer.

Comment: @esac You only need to replace the `call slowOutput.bat` with your command `fetch.exe <options>`

Comment: Does this ever have a collision between writing into the file and reading from the file?